# Can I add ngOnDestroy using a decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

```
class x() {
 @decorator
 someMethod() {
 }
}
```

is there a way to add `ngOnDestroy` to the `x` class using the decorator? I tried following steps:

1 - Add to the target

```
function decorator(target, key, descriptor) {
  target.ngOnDestroy = {...};
  target.ngOnDestroy = {...};
}
```

2 - Add using 'this' where 'this' was the context of 'x' class

```
function decorator(target, key, descriptor) {
  this.ngOnDestroy = {...};
  this['ngOnDestroy'] = {...};
}
```

after each step when I consoled '`this`' or '`target`' I saw there the '`ngOnDestroy`' key but after '`x`' destruction the `ngOnDestroy` didn't fire. Why?

Comment: *Why?* - who knows? It should work as expected. http://plnkr.co/edit/sFGuTPSjJSarEGXMX3MI?p=preview . The question doesn't contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which means that you did something wrong but didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: Thank you, your approval made me a bit more sure about source of the problem. Unfortunately I couldn't paste here the whole code. The problem was that the function that sets the ngOnDestroy was inside getter that was in return. Placing in there was too deep and made it too late to set the ngOnDestroy. The solution is to either place setting ngOnDestroy not deeper than in the first layer of decorator function or (in case we need 'this' in the function) set it there on null and then set it again in getter. Doing it in getter makes us available to change the function, not to declare it.

Comment: I'm not sure what getter thing is supposed to look like. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I meant when you return a descriptor object with custom get function. I had an object like that and inside the get funttion I was adding the ngOnDestroy.

Comment: Why don't you use a class decorator?